# How to merge two owl file (.ttl format) into one new file using owlapi?

Tags: owl, owl-api

In fact, I have already successfully output the new file.
I first load the two ontologies I want to merge and use a merger to merge them, then I use `saveOntology()` to output the file. 
The weird thing is, when I try to load the new file with owlapi, it reports **Either a suitable parser could not be found, or parsing failed.** I mean since the file is generated by owlapi itself, and during the generation no error occurs. Why owlapi cannot parse the file generated by itself successfully?

p.s.

To be more accurate, the error reported should be **cannot be resolved against curent base IRI http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl**

Comment: It would be good if you can share code + data (if possible). and maybe also the OWL API version. Also, did you try to save it in a different format, e.g. RDF/XML?

Comment: @AKSW In fact, i have already found the answer. There are some messy codes in yagoTaxonomy.ttl which cannot be parsed by owlapi.

Comment: I do not understand. You said you loaded the two ontologies, merged them and wrote them back into a single file. This file failed to load afterwards. If something is wrong with one of the files, the parsing would fail already before the merge

Comment: @AKSW. Yes, that's exactly what I feel weird about. Now I know the cause for the errors after merge, but I still don't know why there is no error when loading the original files.